# Integration inequality $\int_0^1 fg\,dx \leq \int_0^1f\,dx\int_0^1g\,dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g \in C[0,1]$, such that $f,g \geq0$, do we have the following inequality 
$$\sqrt{\int_0^1 fg\,dx} \leq \int_0^1 f\,dx \int_0^1 g\,dx.$$
Or in other words can we at least say that

$$\int_0^1 fg\,dx \leq \int_0^1f\,dx\int_0^1g\,dx.$$

Comment: No. Put $f(x)=g(x)=x$. Then RHS=$1/4$, LHS=$1/3$.

Comment: No. A similar (true) result is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or, more generally, Holder's inequality.